# Angular Dialog Params

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want to achieve a dialog which have some API for the data. Before, implementing the dialog, the API is called by the param id through *routerLink* but as I opted for dialog, there is no param for the same so, I'm not able to pass id to dialog for API calling.

I tried to pass the id with dialog create function, but that also didn't work as per the requirement.

**HTML:**

```
<button color="primary" matTooltip="Audit Order" (click)="onCreate(orders.orderId)" style="background-color:rgba(251, 230, 221, 1); border-radius: 5px;">
 AUDIT
</button>
```

**TS:**

```
import { MatDialog, MatDialogConfig } from '@angular/material';
import { AuditPopupComponent } from '../audit-popup/audit-popup.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'kt-audit',
  templateUrl: './audit.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./audit.component.scss']
})
export class AuditComponent implements OnInit {

 constructor(private dailog: MatDialog) {}

 ngOnInit() {}

 onCreate(orderId){
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      this._Order.viewOrders(orderId).subscribe(res => {
        this.orderDetails = res.data;
    });
   });
    const dailogConfig = new MatDialogConfig();
    // dailogConfig.disableClose = true;
    dailogConfig.autoFocus = true;
    dailogConfig.width = "50%";
    this.dailog.open(AuditPopupComponent, dailogConfig);
  }
}
```

**Child component TS:**

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
        this.ps.viewOrders(params['id']).subscribe(res => {
          this.ordersView = res.data;
     });
  });
}
```

Comment: Have a look here: https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview#sharing-data-with-the-dialog-component-

Answer (score 0):

This may not the hint for your solution, but try to avoid nested subscriptions due to maintenance issues on bigger projects.

And also you have to worry about destroying the subscriptions, as long as you're not using them in an angular service

Answer (score 0):

You just have to pass the data to the Dialog via the Dialog Options:

TS:

```
import { MatDialog, MatDialogConfig } from '@angular/material';
import { AuditPopupComponent } from '../audit-popup/audit-popup.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'kt-audit',
  templateUrl: './audit.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./audit.component.scss']
})
export class AuditComponent implements OnInit {

 constructor(private dailog: MatDialog) {}

 ngOnInit() {}

 onCreate(orderId){
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      this._Order.viewOrders(orderId).subscribe(res => {
        this.dailog.open(AuditPopupComponent, {
          autoFocus: true,
          width: "50%",
          data: res.data
        });
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Dialog:

```
import { MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material';
import { Inject } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'dialog-data-example-dialog',
  templateUrl: 'dialog-data-example-dialog.html',
})
export class DialogDataExampleDialog {
  constructor(@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: DialogData) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    this.ordersView = this.data;
  }
}
```